# How to debug a Spring Boot Web Application in STS?

Tags: maven, debugging, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

I am new to the Spring Framework and so I started with the Spring Boot projects.

In particular, I took the https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-secure-jdbc project and modified the pom.xml so that it becomes self contained (replaced spring-boot-samples with spring-boot-starter-parent in the parent->artifactId tag, removed properties node, added in repositories and pluginRepositories from http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-maven-installation).

I successfully built and ran this application outside of STS first with 'mvn spring-boot:run', then imported the Maven project into STS and it builds and runs there successfully.

I am able debug this application by right-clicking on the project folder and choosing Run->Debug As ...->Spring Boot App and the debugger does stop at the breakpoints I've set in the ApplicationSecurity class methods.  However, the browser window does not automatically pop-up in STS nor the system browser (which I expect - is this correct?).

When I browse to localhost (port 8080) using the 'Internal Web Browser' within STS/Eclipse the HTML pages render out but the breakpoints that I've set in the @RequestMapping("/") methods do not get hit  (I suspect that this is probably due to the fact that the browser is in a separate process to the debugger).

So, how do I debug @RequestMapping methods within STS - this would help me to understand the Spring framework better.

I have limited knowledge of Eclipse/STS, so could there be a problem with my installation?

Comment: Does your application have its own main method?

Comment: Yes and I could debug into it before I posted this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use the embedded browser to debug a server (the browser is a separate process). If your `@RequestMapping` breakpoints are not hit then I suspect Spring didn't dispatch to  those routes for whatever reason (maybe security?).

Comment: After commenting out ...
`@Bean
public ApplicationSecurity applicationSecurity() {
    return new ApplicationSecurity();
}`
... the breakpoints were hit in the methods associated with @RequestMapping("/") and @RequestMapping("/foo").  So, disabling security allowed the breakpoints to be hit?!

But with security enabled the pages were rendered correctly (passing the model properties to the view) so it looks to me that those mapped methods were called - is it a feature of WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter to hide calls from the debugger? I don't understand fully understand. Thanks.

Comment: The debugger is deterministic, and unaware of spring security. So if those methods were called, you would have hit a breakpoint. Without seeing your code it's impossible to say more.

Comment: Steps to reproduce:

1. Click the 'Download ZIP' button at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot
2. Unzip the downloaded file to a local folder.
3. Open up STS
4. File->Import ...
5. Under Maven, choose "Existing Maven Projects", click Next
6. Point to the "spring-boot-samples" folder that corresponds to this : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples e.g. C:\dev\java\maventest\spring-boot-master\spring-boot-samples
7.  I left all the (sub) projects selected and clicked Finish

... continued ...

Comment: 8.  Wait until the background process has imported and built all the projects this may take some time.
9.  In the 'spring-boot-sample-web-secure-jdbc' project folder, locate (src/main/java) and open SampleWebSecureCustomApplication.java.  Put breakpoints in the home() & foo() methods (@RequestMapping methods) and a breakpoint one of the start up methods, say addViewControllers().
10. Right-click on the 'spring-boot-sample-web-secure-jdbc' project folder, choose Debug As ...->Spring Boot App
... continued ...

Comment: 11. Confirm that the breakpoint in addViewControllers() method does get hit and click Resume to continue execution.
12. Open up a browser, browse to http://localhost:8080
13. The login page renders out but the breakpoints in the home() & foo() methods never got hit - WHY?
14. Stop the debugger, comment out `@Bean public ApplicationSecurity applicationSecurity() { return new ApplicationSecurity(); }`. Repeat steps 10 to 12 above and the breakpoints in home() & foo() methods get hit.
... continued ...

Comment: NOTE: With the above steps, I reproduced this issue again today without any code or pom.xml changes (other that outlined in the last step).

NOTE: @david-syer, since you are the author of the JUnit test in this project you probably don't need to do these steps but if it doesn't reproduce for you with your existing check out of this github repository then I suggest following these steps.

I'm on a Windows 7 x64 machine with all the latest updates.

(A numbered <ol> list markdown doesn't seem to be working :( )

Comment: You said "the login page renders out but the breakpoints ... never got hit". But the breakpoint is nothing to do with the login page, so I don't understand what you mean. When you login and hit the home page, then the breakpoints are hit, right? So what's the problem?

Comment: Hi dave-syer, apologies I had not gone far enough in my steps to reproduce - I should have added ... after logging in (with user user) the breakpoint does not get hit and also when I browse to /foo on localhost.  However, today it is hitting the the breakpoints in the samples project and in my copy of the 'spring-boot-sample-web-secure-jdbc' project.  I'm not sure what I have done differently but it is working for me now consistently.  Thanks for your time.